# Main function not running after switching to dev branch and upgrading flutter. Giving me below Errors

Tags: flutter, dart

/C:/Intel/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
^^^^^^
/C:/Intel/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
^^^^^^^^
3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Intel\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Intel\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: you need to create a new project

Comment: I switched back to the master branch and still the error are occuring

Answer (score 0):

Please check what version do you have for the SVG package. In case it has a "1.3.0^"  try just "1.3.0" instead. I mean version without the '^' symbol.
This worked for me!